# Trying to prove that $\int \frac{u'(x)}{a^2-u^2(x)}dx = \frac{1}{2a}\ln|\frac{a+u(x)}{a-u(x)}+C$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm learning about integrals so I am just playing around a bit. I tried to find the derivative of:

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{2a}\ln|\frac{a+u(x)}{a-u(x)}+C\\
\\
\Rightarrow & \frac{1}{2a}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln|\frac{a+u(x)}{a-u(x)}+C\right)\\
\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{a+x}{a-x}\right)=& \ \frac{(a+x)'(a-x)-(a+x)(a-x)'}{(a-x)^2}\\
\\
=& \ \frac{(a-x)+(a+x)}{(a-x)^2}= \frac{a+a}{(a-x)^2}=\frac{2a}{(a-x)^2}\\
\\
&\frac{1}{2a}\cdot\frac{2a}{(a-x)^2}=\frac{1}{(a-x)^2}
\end{align*}

This looks correct yet the formula is $\int \frac{u'(x)}{a^2-u^2(x)}\,dx = \frac{1}{2a}\ln|\frac{a+u(x)}{a-u(x)}+C$

But the expansion of $(a-x)^2=a^2-2ax+x^2$, not $a^2-x^2$. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the substitution $t=au(x)$ and use the basic integral
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{1-t^2}=\arg\!\tanh t=\frac12\ln\Bigl(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\Bigr).$$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I say to compute this integral by substitution instead of calculating the derivative of the asserted result.

Comment: Ok, but how do you do that? I didn't quite understand from your example and why arctanh?

Comment: Do you know the formula for integration by substitution?

Comment: Not yet... gotcha, I will keep on reading and I will get back to this when I get to that part. Thanks.